# weird artifacts with render in cycles

Tags: rendering, lighting

[image: this is what happens when i render in cycles, this is the only part in the whole render that dos this]

this is what happens when i render in cycles, this is the only part in the whole render that does this. i tried increasing the samples and it did nothing

Answer (score 3):

That appears to be artifacts from the denoiser. Try disabling the denoiser or tweaking the denoiser settings to reduce the artifacts (reducing Radius and/or Strength can help).

Alternatively, such artifacts can be caused by saving the image in a 'lossy' format (such as JPG) with too low a quality - check your Output format settings.

Answer (score 1):

turns out i was increasing the wrong samples, i was increasing the samples in the viewport and not the render